# Efficient query with Generic Relations

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

These are my models:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.TextField(_('comment'))


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80)         
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_posts")
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'), null=True, blank=True)
```

Now in my views.py I get a post with this istruction:

```
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
```

At this point in my views.py, what is the most efficient query ( with ORM ) to get all comments of that post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)` on the Post, to give you easy access from Post to Comment. Once you've done that, it's a simple backwards relationship:

```
comments = post.comments.all()
```

Note that this isn't really a question of efficiency. Getting all the related items via a backwards generic relationship will always incur at most two queries - one to get the relevant ContentType, which is automatically cached on first look-up, and once to get the actual items.

If you had asked how to get all the comments for multiple posts as efficiently as possible, I'd point you to [my blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/15/django-patterns-part-3-efficient-generic-relations/) for a good technique, but since you haven't I won't because that would just be blog-whoring.